# How do I proxy all local traffic on 127.0.0.1:1080 use nftables tproxy

Tags: vpn, routing, linux-networking, transparent-proxy, nftables

On my desktop linux,I want to surf the Internet through a proxy VPN.
I already have a client for a transparent proxy listing on 127.0.0.1:1080.
I want the traffic generated by the local process to pass through this client.

I know that TProxy is only useful for prerouting,and I need to force the traffic to lo dev.

nftables setting

```
   chain output {
        type route hook output priority mangle;policy accept;
        ip protocol tcp mark set 0x233
    }
   chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        ip protocol tcp nftrace set 1
        ip protocol tcp tproxy to 127.0.0.1:1080
    }
```

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x233 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

But I did not see any information into the PACKET lo network card.
Can anyone help me，it's really hard.